# Lotus Notes- how to change the year in a birthdate to @today

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have to make a calendar view to show employee birthdays.
T want to convert their date of birth so that the year is this year.
So far I have this and have tried various methods but keep getting "incorrect data type" errors.

```
currentYear:=@Year(@Today);
curentmonth:=@Month(DOB);
currentday:=@Day(DOB);
@Date(currentday;currentmonth;currentYear)
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says the correct usage is `@Date(year;month;day)`. As there's no indication of locale-specific treatment of parameters, I believe that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pablo is correct, but you could also take advantage of the very useful @Adjust function:

```
@Adjust(DOB; @Year(@Now)-@Year(DOB);0;0;0;0;0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Today or @Now in a view column formula or anywhere else will result in the view index being constantly out-of-date. If it is a large DB that will be very slow and irritating to the users.

I recommend using a computed field or an agent instead to create a multi-value field with the dates for the next 5-20 years. The agent need only run once a year to keep the docs in your calendar. This is how the Notes calendar keeps anniversaries, birth dates and repeating meetings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and help.
I'll put a field on the form and run an agent as Newbs suggested.
Using the code Phil came up with.
It works well.